# Using Generics with Buffer Class

Tags: java, android, generics, buffer, bytebuffer

I have a class that makes use of a `ByteBuffer`. I currently create the `ByteBuffer` as a `FloatBuffer` in the class' member declarations, e.g.,

```
class MyClass {

    private FloatBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer
        .allocateDirect(4)
        .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
        .asFloatBuffer();

// etc.

}
```

Ideally I would like to make the `ByteBuffer` generic so that I can declare its type when I instantiate the class, but I'm confused as how to achieve this. I was hoping that I could use something like:

```
class MyClass<T extends Buffer> {
```

in the class declaration, but I would still need to determine the correct `ByteBuffer` method to invoke, i.e., `asFloatBuffer()`, `asShortBuffer()`, `asLongBuffer()` etc. Perhaps there is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. The `new` is redundant. It would make more sense to declare it as a `ByteBuffer` and do the `asFloatBuffer()` etc when you know you need them.

Comment: Thanks EJP. Yes, the `new` was a mistake (I'll edit). How would you suggest I declare what type I want the `ByteBuffer` to be in the class instantiation?

Comment: Also, don't I have to declare it as a `FloatBuffer` if I'm using `asFloatBuffer`? I can't use the latter with `ByteBuffer` (incompatible types).

Comment: What part of 'declare it as a ByteBuffer' didn't you understand? You can declare a local variable for the asFloatBuffer() result when you need it, obviously, or just chain the method calls.